# nuxtjs - On first load, home page flashes 'This page could not be found' then loads the actual home page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I hosted my first nuxt app (universal) on cloudways.com. (https://esquad.in) I followed their documentations to start a nodejs server. (https://www.thecloudkeeper.io/how-to-host-a-nodejs-app-on-cloudways/) I am using .htaccess as proxy.

```
# Redirect traffic to your port 3000
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

I am having the issue only on home page. When I load home page, it shows a message 'This page could not be found', then load the actual home page. All other pages working fine (even if I refresh the pages)

You can view my app at https://esquad.in/ (If you check console, it will show the error message Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()), Refresh the home page to see the not found message. (it shows only on home page)

How can I fix this issue?
issue screenshot: https://prnt.sc/t00hnn

Comment: Which nuxt mode do you use? static site, universal?

Comment: I use universal

Comment: I see in the network tab that 4 bundled .js files cannot be found (404). You can check if these files are on the file system. Did you try npm run generate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I updated my .htaccess file

```
# Redirect traffic to your port 3000
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Thankyou, your solution helped me fix similar issue with my project :)